# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn' when pip shows that sklearn is installed

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

When I try to run this to test if everything is installed correctly

```
import sklearn  
print('sklearn: {}'.format(sklearn.__version__))
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Users\matth\Documents\Test Libraies.py", line 20, in <module>  
    import sklearn  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

When I try to test in  my cmd using `pip list` i get

```
Package       Version
------------- ------- 
joblib        0.14.1  
numpy         1.18.4  
pip           20.1  
scikit-learn  0.23.0  
scipy         1.4.1  
setuptools    46.3.0  
threadpoolctl 2.0.0  
wheel         0.34.2
```

I tried to get all of the possible places it could be into the PATH and have gotten nothing. Google also hasn't been much help. I'm new to adding libraries into python but the other 4 I installed worked fine.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

The output of `python -c "import sklearn; sklearn.show_versions()"` is:

```
System:
    python: 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
executable: C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
   machine: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
Python dependencies:
       pip: 20.1
setuptools: 46.3.0
   sklearn: 0.23.0
     numpy: 1.18.4
     scipy: 1.4.1
    Cython: None
    pandas: None
matplotlib: None
    joblib: 0.14.1

Built with OpenMP: True
```

**EDIT 2**

From within the IDE, `import pip;print(pip.main(['list']))` shows:

```
Package            Version
------------------ -------
...
scikit-learn       0.23.0
...
sklearn            0.0
...
```

Comment: Make sure, that pip and Python are linking into same Python version. Just in case, install by using `pip3` and running with `python3` for example

Comment: What version of python are you using?  Also, how do you run this code?  Are you using an IDE, or do you type `python myscript.py` on a command line?

Comment: what's the output of `python -c "import sklearn; sklearn.show_versions()"` when run in command line?

Comment: try to install `scikit-learn`: `pip install -U scikit-learn`

Comment: Im using python 3.8.2 and I have been using the python.org ide

Comment: the oput of python -c "import sklearn; sklearn.show_versions()" is:

System:
    python: 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
executable: C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
   machine: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0

Python dependencies:
       pip: 20.1
setuptools: 46.3.0
   sklearn: 0.23.0
     numpy: 1.18.4
     scipy: 1.4.1
    Cython: None
    pandas: None
matplotlib: None
    joblib: 0.14.1

Built with OpenMP: True

Comment: both using pip3, scikit-learn, pip install -U scikit-learn didnt fix the problem

Comment: From within your IDE, what does `import pip;print(pip.main(['list']))` show?

Comment: Import pip;print(pip.main(['list'])) shows

Comment: Package            Version  
------------------ -------  
attrs              19.3.0  
backcall           0.1.0  
bleach             3.1.5  
colorama           0.4.3  
colored            1.4.2  
cycler             0.10.0  
decorator          4.4.2  
defusedxml         0.6.0  
entrypoints        0.3  
Gooey              1.0.3.1  
ipykernel          5.2.1  
ipython            7.14.0  
ipython-genutils   0.2.0  
ipywidgets         7.5.1  
jedi               0.17.0  
Jinja2             2.11.2  
joblib             0.14.1  
jsonschema         3.2 .0

Comment: jupyter            1.0.0
jupyter-client     6.1.3
jupyter-console    6.1.0
jupyter-core       4.6.3
kiwisolver         1.2.0
MarkupSafe         1.1.1
matplotlib         3.2.1
mistune            0.8.4
mpmath             1.1.0

Comment: nbconvert          5.6.1
nbformat           5.0.6
nose               1.3.7
notebook           6.0.3
numpy              1.18.4
packaging          20.3
pandas             1.0.3
pandocfilters      1.4.2
parso              0.7.0
pickleshare        0.7.5
Pillow             7.1.2
pip                20.1
prometheus-client  0.7.1
prompt-toolkit     3.0.5
psutil             5.7.0
Pygments           2.6.1
pyparsing          2.4.7
pyrsistent         0.16.0
python-dateutil    2.8.1
pytz               2020.1
pywin32            227
pywinpty           0.5.7
pyzmq              19.0.1

Comment: qtconsole          4.7.4
QtPy               1.9.0
scikit-learn       0.23.0
scipy              1.4.1
Send2Trash         1.5.0
six                1.14.0
sklearn            0.0
sympy              1.5.1
terminado          0.8.3
testpath           0.4.4
threadpoolctl      2.0.0
tornado            6.0.4
traitlets          4.3.3
wcwidth            0.1.9
webencodings       0.5.1
widgetsnbextension 3.5.1
wxPython           4.0.7
0

Comment: From within your IDE, what happens when you just type `import sklearn`?

Comment: FYI, it's better if **you** add additional information to your question.  It's easier for new readers to understand your question and it's better if you add it so there won't be any misunderstandings of the new information.  Learning [how to format code on StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) is important too.

Comment: Import sklearn (what was causing an error to start this problem )gets  `   File "C:\Users\matth\Documents\Test Libraies.py", line 24, in <module>
    import sklearn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn' `

Comment: What is `Test Libraies.py`? And what does it have to do with just typing `import sklearn ` in the IDE?

Comment: Its the file I was using to run through. I didnt think to just type it into the IDE but I just did it and it gave

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'`

Comment: This may be an IDE issue. Exactly which IDE are you using, how did you install it, and exactly how do you launch it?

Comment: I downloaded python 3.8.2 from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and opened the IDE from my start menu

Comment: Would have a 32 bit install of python on a 64 bit system affect anything?

Comment: It might if there's a previous or another Python install.

Comment: So you would need to unintall a python 3.6 or so version? That makes since I'll unistall the previous version i have and test everything again.

Comment: As best I can tell I have unistalled all other python versions and tryed uninstalling and reinstalling sklearn but I still get the same no module named sklearn.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that IDE.  Is there a way to install packages from within the IDE?

Comment: I dont belive so.

Comment: You know what Thanks for all the help but I think I'll just use Anaconda its got all the libraries I need already installed.

Comment: OK, good luck with `sklearn`!